# Having error using boxsdk for python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sdk, box

`from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file (client.py, line 3)`

getting error in file: 'boxsdk/client/**init**.py'

unable to use the library

Comment: must be designed for an old python. Can you move `from __future__ imports` at the start of the file? should work (better :))

Comment: worked :)
but they ned to update the sdk

Comment: free software is not what it used to be :) glad that it solved it.